# Ansible and AWS EC2 inventory

Tags: ansible

I'd like to get EC2 instances metadata with Ansible and do something with those instances based on the metadata. However, ec2_facts wants to SSH into instances in order to get the metadata.

I believe it should be possible to obtain the instances metadata without SSH connections.

Could you help me with that please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is information you can retrieve about instances using the aws API but ec_facts does not use it. What that Ansible module does specifically is fetch metadata via `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/` which can only be done from the instance itself.

Some more information about what instance data you wish to fetch would be helpful to know. At this time there is no aws cloud module in core that will retrieve general information about an instance but Ansible makes it easy to write one.

Here is an example of a module that returns information about instances that match a set of tags - https://github.com/edx/configuration/blob/master/playbooks/library/ec2_lookup

Comment: Thank you jarv, ec2_lookup module is exactly I was looking for!